# Grails: what are the minimal properties that must be set inside BuildConfig?

Tags: grails, configuration

What are the minimal properties that *must* be set inside a Grails (2.3.6) app's `BuildConfig.groovy` file?

According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html):

> Grails has a set of core settings that are worth knowing about. Their defaults are suitable for most projects, but it's important to understand what they do because you may need one or more of them later.

However this doesn't necessarily confirm that they *all* have defaults. So I ask: is there a minimal set of properties for this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to set anything in here. If your app uses the default database (H2), the default Grails plugins, and has no JAR dependencies other than those provided by Grails, you don't need to make any changes to it.

However, for most applications the above is not true.